# When publishing a Azure Stream Analytics job from VS 2017, will it drop any data?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-stream-analytics

As the title. If I publish a job from visual studio 2017, what will the job do? Will it restart reading from the same point as it stopped, or start from a new time and miss some data?

Answer (score 0):

When you start an ASA job, there are three kinds of "output start mode" you can choose. If you choose the "latest event" mode, that means you will start to read the event from last stop positon which will not drop any data.

Comment: I know that you can select output start mode when restarting a job from the azure portal. However, when you do publish from within visual studio there are no such options.

Comment: you are right,  if you start from visual studio, you can select the mode. However, If you start it automatically, we will use the last selected mode. Thanks for your feed back, we are consider to fixing this issue